# Draggable Clock Hands for the Math Inept in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, clock, trigonometry, angle

I have a few basic trigonometry questions that will probably make you laugh when I ask them, but because I'm a strong-willed individual, I'm going to ask them anyway! So, math is not my forte. I suck at it. I sucked at it in high school. I didn't even touch it in college. And I try my best to steer clear of it now. However, I'm a developer, so it rears its ugly head almost on a <del>daily</del> hourly basis. Let me tell you about my current situation.

I have an analog clock that I'm drawing entirely in code. I've read up on all sorts of fun trig stuff and scary functions like `atan2`, and I've actually got a clock that changes with the time. It's pretty cool. The problem I'm facing at the moment is that when I drag the hour hand near 360° (or 0°), it "jumps" ahead about 30–60°, then starts spinning like crazy.

Here's a sort of visual idea of what I'm talking about:

[image: Showing where the jump occurs.]

[image: Showing where on the circle, the hour hand doesn't jump.]

I'm currently taking the angle of the drag within the bounds and subtracting the current angle of the hour hand to find a delta value. Then I just add an hour or remove an hour depending on the direction of the drag. Here's what I've got in my `-mouseDragged:` method:

```
if ( self.movingHourHand ) {

    NSPoint location = [self convertPoint:theEvent.locationInWindow fromView:nil];
    CGFloat hourAngle = self.hourHandAngle;
    CGFloat dragAngle = [self angleWithPoint:location];
    CGFloat delta = dragAngle - hourAngle;

    // If the delta angle isn't half of 30.0 degrees
    // (angle for 1 hour) or greater, bail.
    if ( fabs(delta) < (360.0 / 12.0 / 2.0) )
        return;

    NSInteger hourValue;

    //   0° = East
    //  90° = North
    // 180° = West
    // 270° = South

    // If the delta is negative, the dragging direction is clockwise.
    // When moving clockwise, the hour value increases.
    if ( delta < 0.0 ) {
        hourValue = 1;
    }

    // If the delta is positive, the dragging direction is counterclockwise.
    // When moving counterclockwise, the hour value decreases.
    else {
        hourValue = -1;
    }

    self.dateValue = [self.calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitHour 
                                               value:hourDelta 
                                              toDate:self.dateValue
                                             options:0];
}
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff, but I think the main problem is how I'm calculating the "offset" position for 12 o'clock being the start, rather than the normal 3 o'clock. Here's how I calculate an angle from a point:

```
- (CGFloat)angleWithPoint:(NSPoint)point
{
    NSRect rect = self.clockRect;
    NSPoint centerPoint = NSMakePoint(NSMidX(rect), NSMidY(rect));

    CGFloat deltaX = point.x - centerPoint.x;
    CGFloat deltaY = point.y - centerPoint.y;

    CGFloat theta = atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

    if ( theta < 0 ) {
        theta += (2 * M_PI);
    }

    return BSDDegreesFromRadians(theta);
}
```

And here's how I'm getting the angle of my hour hand:

```
// I try my best to stay away from "magic" numbers, 
// even though these are pretty standard values.
//
// ACTotalHours = 12
// ACTotalMinutes = 60
// ACFullRotation = 360

- (CGFloat)angleOfHourHandForHour:(NSUInteger)hour minute:(NSUInteger)minute
{
    if ( hour > ACTotalHours )
        hour -= ACTotalHours;

    // TODO: Uncomment the minute angle code when finished debugging.
    CGFloat hourAngle = hour / ACTotalHours * ACFullRotation;

    // CGFloat minuteAngle = minute / ACTotalMinutes * ACFullRotation;
    // hourAngle += (minuteAngle / ACTotalHours);

    // This is the part I'm horribly unsure of (and is the result of a 
    // huge n00b trying his hand at mathematics):
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    hourAngle = [self offsetAngle:hourAngle];

    // if ( hourAngle >= 360 ) {
    //  hourAngle -= 360;
    // }

    return hourAngle;
}

//
// This seems pretty shoddy, but all of the hands line up properly, so I dunno.
//
- (CGFloat)offsetAngle:(CGFloat)angle
{
    return (360.0 - (angle - 90.0));
}
```

I apologize for the sloppiness, but as you can imagine, I've been pulling things out here and there, and now it's just kind of a mess. So in a nutshell, here's what I'm doing:

1. Get the angle of the hour hand.
2. Get the angle created by the center point of the clock and the drag point.
3. Get the delta of said angles.
4. If the delta is negative, the angle is getting smaller. That means the hour value is increasing (and vice-versa).
5. Increase/decrease my `dateValue` property accordingly.
6. Redraw the clock with the updated angle for the hour hand.

After rereading my post, I don't think I've done a very good job of explaining, but I'm going to get some shuteye. If anyone can figure out what my problem is, I'd be really grateful. If you need a better explanation, I'd be more than happy to give this another go after a good night's sleep. Thanks for reading!

Comment: does the clock work when it runs on its own?  I see this question is very old, but the clock looks amazing!  What project is this for?